# Spring <jee:jndi-lookup> tag & `SAXParseException`

Tags: java, spring

Here are the excerpts of my Spring context `.xml` file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <beans:import
        resource="classpath:com/batch/jobs/data-source-context.xml" />

    <job id="xxxx">
        <step id="loadRecord">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="dtaFileItemReader" writer="dtaGroupWriter"
                    commit-interval="${job.commit.interval}" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>              
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc"></jee:jndi-lookup>        

    <beans:bean id="incrementerParent" class="${batch.database.incrementer.class}">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="incrementerName" value="ID" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I get an exception saying that:

```
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jee:jndi-lookup'
```

Comment: btw: you `using spring-beans-2.0` may you want to upgrade to 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing Spring (beans, aop and tx) 2.0 with the JEE schema from Spring 3.0, which will probably lead to issues.

Comment: you were right. Downloaded the fresh version of Spring and changed all the namespaces. Now its working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Ensure that the namespace definitions in the context xml all point to the *same* version.

Answer (score 10):

You have an incorrect namespace declaration somewhere, probably for beans as well as JEE.

As per the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee), the JEE XMLNS declaration should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like spring did not found the `org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd` at runtime.

This file is located in `spring-context-3.0.x.RELESE.jar`, check that this file is deployed correct.